# How to model form transitioning from square to oval profile?

Tags: modeling

I just picked up Blender as my first 3D modeling tool and I am already very excited about it and all the useful tutorials that are out there.

I am currently in the process of building a 3D model of a hobby project I normally carve out in wood. I have progressed significantly, but I have hit the wall on two points:

1. I am struggling to turn the rectangles at the back and front of my model into oval circles with diameter = inside of rectangle; and
2. I am looking for a function which could make my middle intersection transition into the said oval circles at the back and front.

Please also see reference pictures attached.

[image: First issue]

[image: Intersection 1]

[image: Intersection 2]

[image: Intersection 3]

I have experienced with the sculpting option for item (2) but I am currently nowhere near good enough to make it look good, so I am hopeful that there is an automated option for that. I have come across some tutorials on lofting but seemingly none which resolves it for me.

I shall be grateful for any advice you may have.

Thank you.

Comment: It's a fairly well formed question, but it would benefit greatly if you shared a photo or a sketch of the object you want to model as well, because at the moment there is no way for anyone to know how exactly the desired result would look and that might stop people from attempting to answer in detail. Also keep in mind this is supposed to be one question at a time. In this case it's pretty much the same issue, but if you ask multiple questions in one, it might get closed.

Answer (score 0):

The geometry you have looks like it would be pretty difficult to work with if its possible for this model I would recommend working with less geometry. Here are some approaches you could try.

The subdivision surface modifier adds a smoothing to your model. This would make the model have more spherical.
Exa:[image]
This is a cube with a loopcut and 2nd level subdiv.

you could use a combination of this and creases. *Crease options can be found in the edge menu in edit mode.*
Exa:[image]

if you had less geometry you could try and use bevels to round your corners of the rectangle. *Bevel options can be found in the edge menu in edit mode.*

I would recommend going through some beginner courses on modeling to get more comfortable with the tools.

Hope this gets you started in the right direction.
Cheers!

- Elliot